# Drop index locks

Tags: postgresql, indexing, locking

My Postgres version is 9.6

I tried today to drop an index from my DB with this command:

```
drop index index_name;
```

And it caused a lot of locks - the whole application was stuck until I killed all the sessions of the drop (why it was devided to several sessions?).

When I checked the locks I saw that almost all the blocked sessions execute that query:

```
SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod    
FROM
pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                       ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
WHERE a.attrelid = <index_able_name>::regclass
AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum;
```

Is that make sense that this will block system actions?

So I decided to drop the index with concurrently option to prevent locks.

```
drop index concurrently index_name;
```

I execute it now from PGAdmin (because you can't run it from noraml transaction).

It run over that 20 minutes and didnt finished yet. Index size is 20MB+-.

And when I'm checking the DB for locks I see that there is a select query on that table and that's blocks the drop command.

But when I took this select and execute in another session - this was vary fast (2-3) seconds.

So why is that blocking my drop? is there another option to do that? maybe to disable index instead?

Comment: `DROP INDEX` has to wait until all earlier transactions are done, and all transactions later than `DROP INDEX` have to queue after it.

Answer (score 9):

`drop index` and `drop index concurrently` are usually very fast commands, but they both, as all DDL commands, require exclusive access to the table.

They differ only in how they try to achieve this exclusive access. Plain `drop index` would simply request exclusive lock on the table. This would block all queries (even selects) that try to use the table after the start of the `drop` query. It will do this until it will get the exclusive lock - when all transactions touching the table in any way, which started before the drop command, would finish and the transaction with a `drop` is committed. This explains why your application stopped working.

The `concurrently` version also needs brief exclusive access. But it works differently - it will not block the table, but wait until there no other query touching it and then does its (usually brief) work. But if the table is constantly busy it will never find such a moment, and wait for it infinitely. Also I suppose it just tries to lock the table repeatedly every X milliseconds until it succeeds, so a later parallel execution can be more lucky and finish faster.

If you see multiple simultaneous sessions trying to drop an index, and you do not expect that, then you have a bug in your application. The database would never do this on its own.

Comment: So if drop index blocks select queries (why???) and drop index concurrently blocked by select queries (table is busy all the time like you said), what is the right way to do that? shut down the application???

Comment: Usually applications have some kind of periodic maintenance windows, often every month, so they can for example install operating system security updates. You can postpone your change to the next maintenance window. Or you can just use `drop index concurrently` and eventually it might succeed during some quiet time of day.

I suppose this exclusive access requirement was a design choice - to avoid concurrency issues while doing DDL. [Issues while doing standard insert/update/delete queries are complicated enough already.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html)

Comment: The problem with the 2nd option is that the drop will block other queries.. so I don't want to run it and let it wait.

Comment: `drop index concurrently` will not block other queries. Only plain `drop index` will.

Comment: After the drop index concurrently has started.. all DML can continue noramlly?